# Eclipse plugin for Jade (Node.js template engine)

Tags: eclipse, node.js, plugins, express, pug

I want to make [Eclipse-based Node.js IDE](https://github.com/PaulVI/eclipse-node-ide/)

**How to edit jade files in Eclipse?**

- What is tool for editing *.jade files (with syntax support) in Eclipse IDE?

Is there Eclipse-based editor or plugin for Jade (template engine for Node.js)?

Already looked at (
[jade templating syntax support for eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7528252/jade-templating-syntax-support-for-eclipse)
[Using Haml & Sass with Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474096/using-haml-sass-with-eclipse)
)

- Or is there Eclipse support for Textmate syntax definition files
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22881458/textmate-bundles-for-eclipse

Related
[Syntax highlighting for Jade in Sublime Text 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7666977/syntax-highlighting-for-jade-in-sublime-text-2)

Comment: You've landed on the _Nodeclipse_ Roadmap: https://github.com/Nodeclipse/eclipse-node-ide/blob/master/Roadmap.md#jade-support : ]

Comment: @Lego That is just my Eclipse Node.js IDE at new home at Nodeclipse team.

Answer (score 2):

I found also [Eclipse XTEXT](http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/), but no trace of ready to use language definition for Jade.

[Eclipse plug-in: Create a new file extension for a language not supported by Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838558/eclipse-plug-in-create-a-new-file-extension-for-a-language-not-supported-by-ecl)
[How to setup a new language IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13603829/how-to-setup-a-new-language-ide)

See [question "I want to build a DSL similar to jade (jade-lang.com)" on Eclipse Community Forums](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/428664/)